Masorah parva hapax legomenon
Is there a complete listing of hapax legomenon in the Masorah parva in the Hebrew Old Testament as indicated by the hebrew letter ל with a small dot over it?

To clarify, are you looking for a full list of places where the masorah parva marks a ליתא, or a masoretic note of hapax legomana? If the former, why specify the masorah at all? And if the latter, wouldn't that be in the masorah magna?

here are some lists of hapaxes https://www.tora.us.fm/tnk1/messages/ljon_sikumim_index_0.html https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7236-hapax-legomena

In Ellis Brotzman's Old Testament Textual Criticism (p. 102), he points out two Hebrew words found in Exodus 32:24 (p. 99): הﬨפרקו and אשּׁלכהו. These are marked in the margin with the letter ל with a small dot over it (Masorah para). I was looking for a tabulation of all such notations which "are used only once in the Old Testament in these particular conjugated forms or particular spellings." I was able to find these two examples in Solomon Mandelkern's, Veteris Testamenti Concordantiae, but was just curious if a work is out these with a complete listing of these occurrences. Thanks!
